# What's required for a PhD in pure math at MIT?

Tags: phd, research-process, university

I'm new to college and I was wondering.

I want to complete a PhD in pure math at MIT.

Could you complete a Bachelor's degree at another university or  would you have to get a Master's degree before you could enter the program?

Comment: In the US it's typical to enter PhD studies directly after undergraduate.  Of course, MIT has relatively high standards.

Comment: @Kimball Indeed, similarly to how you need to be relatively good at football to play in the NFL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in the US, particularly for weak or borderline students?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-the-us-particularly)

Answer (score 2):

https://math.mit.edu/academics/grad/admission/faq.php

> **Do I need a master's degree before applying?**
>
> No, a bachelor's degree (or equivalent) is required.